# On equicontinuity of a family of functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $C[a,b]$ denote vector space of continuous functions on the closed interval $[a,b], (a,b\in\mathbb{R})$. Is it true that the family $\mathcal{A}:=\{\int_a^{x}f(t)dt \ | \ f\in C[a,b]\}$ equicontinuous ? I think this is not true. Can anybody provide a counter-example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is equi-continuous then there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|\int_a^{x} f(t) dt -\int_a^{y} f(t) dt| <1$   whenever $f \in C[a,b]$ and $|x-y| <\delta$. Take $x=a, y=a+\frac {\delta} 2$ and put $f(x)=n$. You get $|n(a-a)-n(a+\frac {\delta} 2-a)| <1$ for all $n$ which is obvously false.

Comment: You show that in particular the sequence $(f_n(x))_{n=1}^\infty\subset A$, where$ f_n(x)=\int_a^xn dt$, is not equicontinuous, so proving that the whole family is not equicontinuous. Nice!